# Can jquery change other jquery scripts?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site & added a call to some jQuery in the head for an interactive map I wanted to use. Everything seemed to be fine.

I've now removed the call to the map script from the header & it seems to have broken my menu. It's meant to stay inside the viewport when you scroll down but no longer does.
The strange thing now is that when I put the call to the map jQuery back into the head, the menu works fine & stays within the viewport when scrolling down.

Is it possible that the map jQuery changed the menu code so that it then relied on the map jQuery to function properly? I'm pretty new to jQuery so please go easy on me!

Thanks

Jo

The site is- http://www.thesummitnews.co.uk
The map jquery is- http://www.thesummitnews.co.uk/cssmap-europe-v4-4/jquery.cssmap.js

Comment: Difficult to say what is happening without a deeper analysis but in general JavaScript can access code inside other .js/ inside iframes/ frames on same page - depending on origin (which URL the contents of frame came from).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The jQuery for the map was on a different URL to the site I'm working on but I've since copied it onto the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general JavaScript can access code inside other .js/ inside iframes/ frames on same page - depending on origin (which URL the contents of frame/ JS source came from).